# AND/OR & Minimum Should Match with edismax query in Solr

Tags: solr, solrnet

I have integrated Solr in an eCommerce site. Now I want to use operator AND/OR in Edismax Search query between my search keywords. If I use AND operator I want to query like **Ankita AND Patel** and if I use OR operator then it would be like: **Ankita OR Patel**

> Please note I have implemented minimum should match.

How can I perform query with operators into Solr? Will it affect the result with minimum should match values?

Previously I add operators between search keywords then pass following query:

```
 results = solrCustomWorker.Query(new SolrQuery(keyword), options);
```

but it won't work as per operator values. It gives the same result with whatever the operator with same **mm** value. For example if mm= 50% then result is same for both operator.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum Should Match, i.e. MM will work only with Solr search queries where no operator is passed into search query. If any of the operator (AND/OR) is passed to the Solr search query, in that case value of mm is insignificant and will not impact results. So you can either have operator defined into the search query or let it go undefined and use minimum should match.

Moreover, it is preferable to use minimum should match as you can define how many words in the search phrase should match especially for longer phrases which is not possible when using operator.

Answer (score 3):

`mm` is meant to work with a series of terms, where the `mm` parameter tells Solr how many of the terms has to match depending on the parameters given. That means that any boolean operator doesn't really make sense, as its meant to work with general free form input.

If you need to express "this field has to match" in the same context as using `mm`, use a filter query `fq` to filter the list of matching documents.

Comment: Okay. I will check this. Can you please suggest How can I perform AND/OR query with Edismax in Solr?

Comment: You can perform it just as you said, with AND / OR between the terms. But the `mm` setting may cause issues with what you expect the result to be.

Comment: Yes, But I want to perform edismax query on multiple fields. How can I do that in Solr?

Comment: Use the `qf` parameter (query fields). You can also weight the fields independently.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with minimum should match - it interferes with boolean operators.

The only workaround I found is grouping the terms with parenthesis:
(Ankita OR Patel) should work as expected because the group is counted as a single term.